# Parameter discovery is not supported for connections using GenericDatabase.

Tags: enterprise-library-5, dbconnection, dbproviderfactories, data-access-app-block

I have been trying create my own DbProvider and configure it with EnterpriseLibrary but I'm running through below issue

**Parameter discovery is not supported for connections using GenericDatabase. You must specify the parameters explicitly, or configure the connection to use a type deriving from Database that supports parameter discovery.**

I have Created Connection class which implements DbConnection and other classes like classes which implmenets  DbCommand etc

I have overriden the DbConnection class and the methods which I dont know implementation I have thrown Not implemented exception like

```
public override string Database
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImpelmentedException();
            }
        }
```

And I have created enterpriselibrary connection as below

```
public Database GetConnection()
        {
    CustomDbProviderFactory obj = new CustomDbProviderFactory();
                    GenericDatabase db = new GenericDatabase("server=****;Request Timeout=3000000;", obj);
                    return db;
}
```

but when I execute DataReader with conection string and command I 'm getting issue I have mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue,
While using generic database object , I was using like this

```
db.ExecuteReader("Select * from employees");
```

instead it should be

```
db.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text,"Select * from employees");
```